# Mass Migration Plesk 12.5.30 error

Tags: migration, plesk

With Plesk 12.5.30, Mass Transfer Script is not working.
(https://kb.plesk.com/113283)

The script is blocked on the message "Waiting for migration task"

print "Waiting for migration task #$task_id\n";

Is there anything I can do?

The probleme is : No free IPs to map shared IP ''

Answer (score 0):

It is very old script for old Plesk versions. Use modern Plesk Migrator http://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/migration-guide/introduction.75496/

Comment: So, how to add this command in cronjob :
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/modules/panel-migrator/plesk-migrator check

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok.
This is solution : 
Cron Job
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/modules/panel-migrator/plesk-migrator generate-migration-list --overwrite && /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/modules/panel-migrator/plesk-migrator check && /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/modules/panel-migrator/plesk-migrator transfer-accounts && /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/modules/panel-migrator/plesk-migrator test-all

Thanks You !